# Очередность нажатия и движения button

Tags: java, android

Есть 3 кнопки (на самом деле их больше), которые располагаются на своих позициях.

Для примера:

- исходная позиция: pos1(50, 50), pos2(50, 60), pos3(50, 70).
- конечная позиция: pos1A(0, 50), pos2A(0, 60), pos3A(0, 70).

При нажатии на любую кнопку срабатывает очередность - та, что нажата первой - идет на позицию 1А, 
вторая - 2А, третья - 3А.

Переместить кнопку на нужную позицию не проблема, но не могу понять - как динамически определить очередность нажатия?

Пытался сделать постановку на точки типа флагами, но не вышло:

```
if (this.status1 == 0) {
    shw1.animate().translationY(0f).translationX(50f).setDuration(4000);
    this.status1 = 1;
} else if (this.status1 == 1) {
    shw1.animate().translationY(0f).translationX(60f).setDuration(4000);
    this.status1 = 2;
}
```

Дурацкая идея, согласен.

Comment: Так вроде рабочая идея с флагом, что не работает-то?

Comment: List заполните координатами, при нажатии берете 0 элемент и перемещаете кнопку, потом удаляете его из списка и т.д.

Comment: 2: **Alex_Skvortsov** по диее должно было работать, да, но отправляет по порядку - первую всегда на первую позицию, вторую на вторую. С утра на свежую голову еще раз попробую.   2: **Style-7** спасибо за идею! Получается идем по порядку. Должно сработать.